# How to save someone's whatsapp status using Lumia 535?

Tags: whatsapp, nokia-lumia-535

I can see  all WhatsApp photos and videos when I open gallery . But I checked everywhere and couldn't find where those media files are located. I searched in WhatsApp folder and could see only folder named 'backup' there.BUT In other mobiles, in medias of whatsapp, it shows .statuses, audio, documents, images,profile photos so how to see the .statuses in lumia 535? So please give your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Download profile pic saver for whatsapp

Comment: No way!
But if anyone has got a way he/she can please let us know about it